# How can I create bean with request scope based in non web context?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web, servlets

Context:-
I have a spring boot application in which there is a filter, interceptor, controllers and then there is a service, we have a bean which is request based in which we set information related to user based on the request, it gets injected using ObjectFactory and in filters and interceptors we inject like above and set the information RequestContextInfo. In normal web context the flow is when user makes a http call flow goes to filter-> interceptor -> controllers -> service -> back to client. In this flow request based bean will get autmatically created and injected by spring.

Problem:
Now in the same spring boot application I have a Kafka consumer which has a thread pool of size n consumer will get the request payload from the queue and submit to one of the worker thread, kafka consumer has the dependency of the spring controller method which method it needs to call to serve the request, it can directly call the controller method. Now this thing is happening by a worker thread in a non web context mode and **that request bean is not getting initialised and there is no user related information. ** that other depedency need.
Note:
I can't make an http call with localhost from kafka consumer
I can't create a request context with new keyword and set it in ThreadLocal

1. Tried creating requestcontextinfo and set it in thread locale in that case I had to modify the code

Comment: Cannot you include the request-based data in the queue entry (together with the request payload)?

Comment: You cannot. There is no web related request so no way to bind to that. And please don't ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77278806/how-can-i-make-a-call-to-rest-controller-in-a-non-web-request-mode) again, just because the comments point you to the same conclusion.